# Integrating tensorflow in a larger C++ project -- Library conflicts

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

**Objective:** Integrate tensorflow into a larger project.

**Solution**: 1) Integrate tensorflow into cmake by passing appropriate arguments to bazel and get a working build.
              2) Unzip the *.whl file to get the library and headers.

**Problem:** Tensorflow builds but has its own header files for protobufs and Eigen. My project also depends on these two libraries and the versions might mismatch. However, I can use the libraries that tensorflow fetches and replace the one we currently use. We currently build protobuf in our system.

**Question:** I can find the protobuf and Eigen header files used by tesorflow inside the whl files built, but I cannot find the `.so` files.

My understanding of bazel is low, but it might be that it is removing the `.so` files from the sandbox it uses, I am not sure.

What can I do to always fetch the lib and include folders for tensorflow dependencies that it dowloads. Namely, protobuf.  Eigen is header only.

*Tried already:* search in `~/.cache/bazel/` directory.